# The sequence 8, a, b, 36 is arithmetic with respect to the first 3 terms and geometric to last 3 - what can a and b be?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $8, a, b, 36$ is an arithmetic sequence with respect to the first 3 terms and geometric with respect to the last 3 terms. What are all possible values of a and b? My attempts at solving this problem have so far failed. Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have form the first condition:
$$a=8+d$$ and $$b=8+2d$$ and from the second
$$b=aq$$
$$36=aq^2$$
You get the equations $$b=8+2(a-8)$$ and $$36=a\cdot \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2$$

Comment: I got this, but not sure what to do next. Thank you.

Comment: You must eliminate $d$ and $q$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  When is a sequence $x,y,z$:

-arithmetic?

-geometric?

---

You should get $2a=8+b$ and $b^2=36a$. Now solve the system...

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you get those two equations?

Comment: Did you answer the question?

Comment: I can solve that system of course but I don't understand how you got the 2 equations.

Comment: Can you write down when is sequence $x,y,z$ arithmetic?

Comment: Oh thank you so much I solved it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

The first $3$ terms of the sequence $8, a, b, 36$ are in AP

So $ a-8 = b-a$ as the difference is same.

So you have $2a= b +8$ ...(1)

Similarly, the last $3$ terms are in GP,

So, the ratio of third to second term will be equal to the ratio of fourth to third term

$\therefore \dfrac{b}{a} = \dfrac{36}{b} \implies b^2 = 36a $

Solve them, and you should get $b = 24$ or $b=-6$ put these values in (1) to get corresponding values of a